# get springboot to route to your subdomain as opposed to localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf, caddy

Let's say I have a domain "example.com". Right now, using caddy, I have configured example.com to be a proxy for a springboot application running on localhost 8080. How do you properly go to other routes within the application? For example, if I go to https://example.com/user, the url will be: example.com/user. but if I route from within the springboot app from there to /login (lets say using return new RedirectView("/login") at the end of the user route in the controller), it will redirect me instead to http:serverIpAdress:8080/login. How could I get this to route to https://example.com/login?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with Spring; Caddy needs to be configured properly as follows:

```
subdomain {                                                                       
    proxy / ipAddress:port { 
        transparent                                                                   
    }                                                                                         
}
```

1) be careful with the spacing in the caddyfile. I had originally tried this and it did not work, and I believe the reason is because i created the file like this:subdomain {
    proxy / ipAddress:port {        transparent }}
2) little bit of confusion that it did work, as from many places I have seen on the internet it appeared they removed transparent from the api